# Azure Stream Analytics - Joining Two Streaming Source

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-eventhub

I am trying to join 2 Streaming Source which produces the same data output from EventHub.
I am trying to find the Maximum Open Price for the Stock every 5 mins and trying to write it to the the Table. I am interested in the time at within the 5 min window at which the stock was maximum and the window time.
I used the below mentioned query but it isn't producing any output for the same.
I think I have messed the joining the condition.

````
WITH Source1 AS (
SELECT
    System.TimeStamp() as TimeSlot,max([open]) as 'MaxOpenPrice'
    FROM
    EventHubInputData  TIMESTAMP BY TimeSlot
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(minute,5)
),
Source2 AS(
SELECT EventEnqueuedUtcTime,[open]
FROM EventHubInputDataDup TIMESTAMP BY EventEnqueuedUtcTime),
Source3 as (
select Source2.EventEnqueuedUtcTime as datetime,Source1.MaxOpenPrice,System.TimeStamp() as TimeSlot 
    FROM  Source1
    JOIN Source2 
    ON Source2.[Open] = Source1.[MaxOpenPrice] AND DATEDIFF (minute,Source1,Source2) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
    )
SELECT datetime,MaxOpenPrice,TimeSlot
INTO EventHubOutPutSQLDB
FROM Source3   ```
````

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the following points:
- Why are you timestamping by TimeSlot in Source1, and EventEngueuedUtcTime in Source 2?
- Why did you feel you needed to duplicate the input? EventHubInputData and EventHubInputDataDup?

Comment: @FlorianEiden : We need to have a time difference between the two sources. And Yes I could have used the same Input and used the different name as an alias. I tried that as well but didnt get the result and to make it clear I used 2 different Input.. I am timestamping it on TimeSlot in Source1 since its the time at which the maximum price is calculated and the next one at EvenEnqueued since its time at which the openprice data is fetched from the source..

Answer (score 0):

The logic is good here. First you identify the maximum value on each window of 5 minutes, then you lookup in the original stream the time at which it happened.

```
WITH MaxOpen5MinTumbling AS (
SELECT
   --TickerId,
   System.TimeStamp() AS WindowEnd, --this always return the end of the window when windowing
   MAX([open]) AS 'MaxOpenPrice'
FROM EventHubInputData --no need to timestamp if using ingestion time
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(minute,5)
)

SELECT
   --M.TickedId,
   M.WindowEnd,
   M.MaxOpenPrice,
   O.EventEnqueuedUtcTime AS MaxOpenPriceTime
FROM MaxOpen5MinTumbling M
LEFT JOIN EventHubInputData O
   ON M.MaxOpenPrice = o.[open]
   AND DATEDIFF(minute,M,O) BETWEEN -5 AND 0 --The new timestamp is at the end of the window, you need to look back 5 minutes
   --AND M.TickerId = O.TickerId
```

Note that at this point you could get multiple results per time window if the max price happens multiple times.

Comment: So I think its the DATEDIFF where I messed it up. Thanks for the input. Will let you know on the outcomes..